# Usage of 'much' as a noun

Tags: word-usage

Why can I use "much" in a sentence like:

> Much has changed here recently.

I've seen a lot in the literature about "nothing/not much" being used, but not without negation or in interrogatives.

Comment: @BillJ - Your initial "no" is confusing, so just to clarify: yes, one may use "much" like this, but no, it's not considered a noun. Correct?

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, you can use the word 'much' as in your sentence.

Comment: @BillJ in *Much has changed here recently*, what is the *x* that has been 'fused' with much?

Comment: I've converted my message into an answer.

Comment: "Much" can be used as a pronoun, in addition to being used as an adverb.

Comment: @Lawrence Check edits, that fragment wasn't present in my original post.

Comment: @Przeszczep Quite so. I'll withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Oxford English Dictionary, 'much' has many possible functions in a sentence. In the usage in the question, it would be a pronoun - substituting a noun phrase. 
One of its many definitions in the OED is C. 1a:

> "*A great deal, a great quantity*"
>
> E.g. "Much is due to the prejudices of well-meaning but uncultured people."
>   or "Much has been done in the way of improving the Schizanthus"

So to answer the question: yes, you can use it as you do in that sentence.
However, both the OED and the experts from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers) state that it is used more in negative phrases.

Answer (score 6):

"Much" is a degree determiner which typically occurs in NPs with non-count nouns, as in *I don't have much money* where "much" is determiner and "money" is head of the NP. But in your example, it's a special kind of 'fused determiner-head' construction where fused-head "much" has an inanimate, abstract interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an example of language changing by common usage. "Much has changed' is something I have heard, usually on TV. It probably should be, "So much has changed."

It is similar to, "It's me." While I was growing up, a teacher would have refused this as incorrect and today, no one notices. When was the last time you heard, "It is I."?

Comment: The last time I heard it was in _'Allo 'Allo_. The old idiot who thought he was good at disguise had the catch phrase "It is I, leClerc!"

Comment: so perhaps as late as 1992 -- much later than I did!

Comment: Yes, but only in a comedy set in WW2!

Answer (score 0):

This usage is correct. *Much* can be used as a noun:

> You have much to learn.

or as an adjective:

> There was much fanfare for their arrival.